# Change system:index of FeatureCollection ID in GEE to use Asset ID

Tags: google-earth-engine, javascript, remote-sensing, ndvi

I have a FeatureCollection with points loaded from an asset (shapefile). Since the system:index is empty, gee assigns a weird index to each feature (e.g. 000000000001, 0000000000a).Which causes problems when I export my Timeseries CSV file as I want it to show the Sample_ID found in my asset (shapefile) Sample ID in the asset like the picture below rather than the GEE assigned feature ID.
Link to code https://code.earthengine.google.com/?noload=1&scriptPath=users%2Fmpalasimbarashe%2FProject1%3AKNDVI%2FTableWIth_Null

[image: Image of Asset ID]

```
/// IMPORTING THE FEATURE COLLECTION ///
var points = points.map(function(feature){
  return ee.Feature(feature.geometry(), {'id': feature.id()})
})
Map.addLayer(points,{color:'green'},'Root Locations')
Map.centerObject(points,10)
print(points)

/// FILTERING THE SENTINEL IMAGE COLLECTION ////
function maskCloudAndShadows(image){
  var cloudProb = image.select('MSK_CLDPRB');
  var snowProb = image.select('MSK_SNWPRB');
  var cloud = cloudProb.lt(5);
  var snow = snowProb.lt(5);
  var scl = image.select('SCL');
  var shadow = scl.eq(3); //3 = cloud shadow
  var cirrus = scl.eq(10); // 10 = cirrus
  
  var mask = (cloud.and(snow)).and(cirrus.neq(1)).and(shadow.neq(1));
  return image.updateMask(mask);
}

/// DATE RANGE FOR THE TIME SERIES ///
var startDate =  new Date ('2020-10-01')
var endDate =  new Date ('2021-05-30')



var addKNDVI = function(image){
  
  var RED = image.select('B4');
  var NIR = image.select('B8');
  
  /// COMPUTE D2 A RENAME TO d2 ///
  var D2 = NIR.subtract(RED).pow(2)
    .select([0],['d2']);
 
  /// GAMMA DEFINED AS 1/sigma^2
  var gamma = ee.Number(4e6).multiply(-2.0);

/// COMPUTE KERNEL (k) AND KNDVI ///

  var k = D2.divide(gamma).exp();
  var kndvi = ee.Image.constant(1)
    .subtract(k).divide(ee.Image.constant(1).add(k))
    .select([0],['kndvi']).clip(points);
    
     return image.addBands(ee.Image([kndvi]));
 
};

/// IMPORTING THE IMAGE COLLECTION

var collection = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_SR')
                   .filterDate(startDate, endDate)
                   .map(maskCloudAndShadows)
                   .map(addKNDVI)
                   .filter(ee.Filter.bounds(points))
                   
/// VIEWING THE MAX IN THE COMPOSITE ////
 var vizParams = { bands: ['B4','B3','B2'] , min: 0, max: 2000}
 Map.addLayer(collection.max(),vizParams, 'collection')

var testPoint = ee.Feature(points.first())

//Map.centerObject(testPoint, 10)

/// TIMESERIES CHART FOR SINGLE LOCATION ///
var chart = ui.Chart.image.series({
    imageCollection: collection.select('kndvi'),
    region: testPoint.geometry()
    }).setOptions({
      interpolateNulls: true,
      lineWidth: 1,
      pointSize: 3,
      title: 'KNDVI over Time at a Single Location',
      vAxis: {title: 'KNDVI'},
      hAxis: {title: 'Date', format: 'YYYY-MMM', gridlines: {count: 12}}
    })
print(chart)

//// TIMESERIES CHART FOR MULTIPLE LOCATIONS ////
var chart = ui.Chart.image.seriesByRegion({
    imageCollection: collection.select('kndvi'),
    regions: points,
    reducer: ee.Reducer.mean()
})
print(chart)

/// HANDLING MASKED PIXELS ///
var triplets = collection.map(function(image) {
  return image.select('kndvi').reduceRegions({
    collection: points, 
    reducer: ee.Reducer.mean().setOutputs(['kndvi']), 
    scale: 10,
  })// reduceRegion doesn't return any output if the image doesn't intersect
    // with the point or if the image is masked out due to cloud
    // If there was no ndvi value found, we set the ndvi to a NoData value -9999
    .map(function(feature) {
    var kndvi = ee.List([feature.get('kndvi'), -9999])
      .reduce(ee.Reducer.firstNonNull())
    return feature.set({'kndvi': kndvi, 'imageID': image.id()})
    })
  }).flatten();
  
var format = function(table, rowId, colId) {
  var rows = table.distinct(rowId); 
  var joined = ee.Join.saveAll('matches').apply({
    primary: rows, 
    secondary: table, 
    condition: ee.Filter.equals({
      leftField: rowId, 
      rightField: rowId
    })
  });
         
  return joined.map(function(row) {
      var values = ee.List(row.get('matches'))
        .map(function(feature) {
          feature = ee.Feature(feature);
          return [feature.get(colId), feature.get('kndvi')];
        });
      return row.select([rowId]).set(ee.Dictionary(values.flatten()));
    });
};
var sentinelResults = format(triplets, 'id', 'imageID');

/// GRANULE OVERLAPS ///
var merge = function(table, rowId) {
  return table.map(function(feature) {
    var id = feature.get(rowId)
    var allKeys = feature.toDictionary().keys().remove(rowId)
    var substrKeys = ee.List(allKeys.map(function(val) { 
        return ee.String(val).slice(0,8)}
        ))
    var uniqueKeys = substrKeys.distinct()
    var pairs = uniqueKeys.map(function(key) {
      var matches = feature.toDictionary().select(allKeys.filter(ee.Filter.stringContains('item', key))).values()
      var val = matches.reduce(ee.Reducer.max())
      return [key, val]
    })
    return feature.select([rowId]).set(ee.Dictionary(pairs.flatten()))
  })
}
var sentinelMerged = merge(sentinelResults, 'id');


//// EXPORTING MULTIPLE LOCATION TIMESERIES ///
Export.table.toDrive({
    collection: sentinelMerged,
    description: 'Multiple_Locations_KNDVI_time_series',
    folder: 'earthengine',
    fileNamePrefix: 'Kndvi_time_series_multiple',
    fileFormat: 'CSV'
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by using a generic function to remove this "weird" index property and, afterward, setting your desired id that identifies each feature. Code snippet looks as follows. Complete code is [here](https://code.earthengine.google.com/1d00304285f4e9ec2770c97c7350ab3c?noload=1).

```
// Generic Function to remove a property from a feature
var removeProperty = function(feat, property) {
  var properties = feat.propertyNames();
  var selectProperties = properties.filter(ee.Filter.neq('item', property));
  return feat.select(selectProperties);
};

// remove property id in each feature
sentinelMerged = sentinelMerged.map(function(feat) {
  feat = removeProperty(feat, 'id');
  return feat.set('id', ee.Feature(feat).id());
});
```

After running complete code in GEE code editor, I ran the task and CSV obtained file has corresponding id in desired way. It can be observed in following picture.

[image]

**Editing Note:**

For pairing 'id' and 'Sample_ID' you first need to create a dictionary at the beginning of the code as follows:

```
/// IMPORTING THE FEATURE COLLECTION ///
var points = points.map(function(feature){
  var sample_id = feature.get('Sample_ID');
  return ee.Feature(feature.geometry(), {'id': feature.id()})
    .set('Sample_ID', sample_id);
});

Map.addLayer(points,{color:'green'},'Root Locations');
Map.centerObject(points,10);
print(points);

var points_list = points.toList(points.size());

var keys = points_list.map(function (ele) {

  return ee.Feature(ele).get('id');
  
});

var values = points_list.map(function (ele) {

  return ee.Feature(ele).get('Sample_ID');
  
});

var dict = ee.Dictionary.fromLists(keys, values);
```

Afterward, you set 'Sample_ID' property in merge function as in following code snippet:

```
/// GRANULE OVERLAPS ///
var merge = function(table, rowId) {
  return table.map(function(feature) {
    var id = feature.get(rowId)
    var allKeys = feature.toDictionary().keys().remove(rowId)
    var substrKeys = ee.List(allKeys.map(function(val) { 
        return ee.String(val).slice(0,8)}
        ))
    var uniqueKeys = substrKeys.distinct()
    var pairs = uniqueKeys.map(function(key) {
      var matches = feature.toDictionary().select(allKeys.filter(ee.Filter.stringContains('item', key))).values()
      var val = matches.reduce(ee.Reducer.max())
      return [key, val]
    })
    
    var sample_id = dict.get(ee.Feature(feature).get('id'));
    
    return feature.select([rowId]).set(ee.Dictionary(pairs.flatten()))
                                  .set('Sample_ID', sample_id);
  });
};
```

Complete code can be accessed [here](https://code.earthengine.google.com/1e38a4538c8fe421e70515483072cfca?noload=1).

Comment: Yes is there any way that the code can utilise the ID found on the asset, for example, the one in the picture I have now put above so that when the CSV is exported it uses the Sample_ID string?

Comment: Yes, there is a way. Please see my **Editing Note**.